# Нижний скролл

Tags: joomla, bootstrap

При верстке адаптивного шаблона на joomla с помощью bootstrap появился нижний скролл, при прокрутке которого видно конец шапки и там далее пустота. При масштабировании все хорошо, сетка работает нормально. Не пойму, откуда он появился, я убирал полностью все css стили, даже весь код в index.php убирал, но скролл так и остался. Помогите, откуда он мог взяться?Буквально вчера я его не видел.

Comment: Чтобы быстро выявить проблему, надо смотреть сайт

Answer (score 1):

Прописал вместо `<div class="row"` `"row-fluid"` - проблема исчезла. Вопрос: почему? Если в 3-м Бутстрапе нет класса  `"row-fluid"`, а вместо него просто `"row"`.